# How to find a *to-be-published* paper

Tags: citations, physics

An article I'm reading references another article as:

> [6] J. Wess and B. Zumino, CERN preprint TH 1857 (1974), Nucl. Phys. B, to be published

It is explained in the article I'm reading that "all unexplained notation in the present paper can be found in ref. [6]", so it is quite an important reference. The problem is that I can't find it anywhere. Neither in *Nuclear Physics B*, nor on the [CERN document server](https://cds.cern.ch/collection/Preprints?ln=en). The [elsevier page](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370269374903104) of the article I'm reading is also no help.

How am I supposed to find this article? Is it possible that it was never published after all?

Comment: Did you search "Supergauge invariant extension of quantum electrodynamics" in Google Scholar? It is Ref.TH.1857-CERN

Comment: You find it by using a real search engine. In Web of Science, searching on the two authors and a generous year range yielded 4 possible hits between 1972 and 1976. Or, you go ask your local research librarian and let them introduce you to the tools available locally.

Comment: @JonCuster That would make a good answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following from a Google search: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(74)90355-1. If that's not it, then browse through the archive of Nuclear Physics B for 1974, from [61(1)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/nuclear-physics-b/vol/68/issue/1) to [83(3)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/nuclear-physics-b/vol/83/issue/3), perhaps going a little further (maybe it didn't appear in 1974). Maybe there's a faster way, e.g., an author index for Nuclear Physics B.

Using a more directed Google search, namely,

`https://www.google.com/search?q=1974%20Wess%20Zumino%20site:https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/`

I found: https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(74)90578-4. My search uses three key pieces of information: publication year (`1974`) and author names (`Wess` and `Zumino`). Moreover, I limit my search to `https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/`, by prepending that url with `site:`. (In the above URL, each `%20` represents a space. You can
enter the following into Google Search: `1974 Wess Zumino site:https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/`, adapting for your needs.)

Comment: Thank you for looking, but that's reference [1] from the same article. I was also hoping for a more general strategy for finding elusive references.

Comment: @Simon It's difficult to answer your question with so little information, perhaps mention [1]. (As it stands, it's probably a shopping question.) _I was also hoping for a more general strategy for finding elusive references:_ That's perhaps a different question. My edited answer gives a slow approach.

Comment: My second edit gives a faster approach, which gives another potential hit.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to contact the first author (or try the other authors). It may be the the paper was never published, or if it was it ended up in a different journal or published in a different year (which can make tracking down harder).

The difficulty here is that the paper was from ~1974 so it may be tricky to track down the current contact information for the person (they may not be in academia anymore or even alive). Depending how well known that person was in your field you may want to check with other people in your department if they know how to reach them. If that fails then you can try talking to your University library, they usually have people whose job is to help find difficult to find papers.

Comment: And 1974 was way before arXiv existed.